# Does a cafe card bonus apply to all players?

Tags: chez-geek

In the game **Chez Geek** cafe cards have a cost of 1 but a bonus that reads

> While a Café card is in play, there is no cost to play further Café cards (though it still takes free time).

Does this bonus apply to all roommates in the game or only the person who played it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have always played it so that the Café bonus applied to all players.

I can find no direct rule citation on this however if they were meant to only apply to the person who played the card it would have specifically said, "While a Café card is in your room" much like many other cards do.